# how to validate multiple images in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to validate images, so a user should only enter five images(maximum) and also he should not be able to upload video , ai ,psd and etc. So far when I try to upload a video it shows no errors and it does not upload the product, if I try to upload other files like psd it shows an error.

> Illuminate \ Http \ Exceptions \ PostTooLargeException

How can I validate only five images(maximum) to be uploaded and also only these type of files `mimes:jpeg,jpg,png`?

code

**Controller**

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate(
        $request,
        [
            'photos' => 'required',
            'photos.*' => '|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png',
        ]);

    foreach ($request->photos as $photo) {
        $filename = $photo->store('public/photos');
        ProductsPhoto::create([
            'product_id' => $product->id,
            'filename' => $filename
        ]);
    }
}
```

Blade template

```
<input multiple="multiple" name="photos[]" type="file">
```

Answer (score 2):

> If I try to upload other files like psd it shows an error `Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\PostTooLargeException`

The `PostTooLargeException` is thrown when the the payload is higher than the `upload_max_filesize` of your server config (you can customize this, of course). This can always be thrown if the user try to upload a video for example. Now, you can treat this in different ways (not exclusive):

- A fron-end validation to ensure the max upload size.
- A way to handle this response error in your front-end.
- Specify a validation rule to restrict the max upload size of the uploaded files to avoid reaching the max allowed.

For the latter option, you can use the [max](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-max) rule that follows the validation of the [size](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-size) validation rule. From the docs:

> #### max:value
>
> The field under validation must be less than or equal to a maximum
>   value. Strings, numerics, arrays, and files are evaluated in the same
>   fashion as the size rule.
>
> #### size:value
>
> The field under validation must have a size matching the given value.
>   For string data, value corresponds to the number of characters. For
>   numeric data, value corresponds to a given integer value. **For an
>   array, size corresponds to the `count` of the array**. **For files,
>   size corresponds to the file size in kilobytes.**

So in your case you can check the uploaded files:

```
$this->validate(
    $request, 
    [
    'photos' => 'required',
    'photos.*' => 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,png|max:4000', // e.g., each file should be less than 4MB
   )];
```

Related to the next matter:

> How can I validate only five images(maximum) to be uploaded?

You can use the same rule but now validating the array size:

```
$this->validate(
    $request, 
    [
    'photos' => 'required|array|max:5', // <----
    'photos.*' => 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,png',
   )];
```

Of course you can combine this restrictions to accomplish your desired behaviour.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I wanted to limit the psd, ai and other files type, I just want a user to upload only `mimes:jpeg,jpg,png` types of file because  even if I change size it still shows an error also a user can upload psd, and other file which I don't want. @HCK

Comment: @user11710915 that is already handled. Check my answer, your can mix several validation rules. As you can see I never removed the `mimes:jpeg,jpg,png` rule, I just added a validation to limit the file size and also the amount of files that can be included in the `photos` array. Check again my full answer to see how this is resolved.

Comment: I have checked and the `array|max:5` works fine  but this `'photos.*' => 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,png|max:4000',` is not working because I can still upload a short video clip  and other psd which I don't want . I want to upload only images not videos, psd, ai etc @HCK

Comment: Try this. Instead of using `mimes:jpeg,jpg,png` use this: `mimetypes:image/jpeg,image/png,image/jpg`

Answer (score 0):

Its simple, I have done it earlier :

```
$galleryImageCount = 0; // count the number of existing images if needed
$galleryImageRules = ['bail|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:5120','bail|sometimes|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:5120'];
$imageRule = [];

for ($i = 0; $i < (5 - $galleryImageCount); $i++) {
        $rule = ($i == 0) ? $galleryImageRules[0] : $galleryImageRules[1];
        $key = 'gallery_image.' . $i;
        $imageRule[$key] = $rule;
}

$this->validate(
    $request,
    $imageRule);
//Replace 'gallery_image' with 'photos' in your case.
```

- Cheers!!!

Comment: Your answer solves this problem `How can I validate only five images(maximum)` but it is not solving  the other one because I can still upload psd, ai files while I just want to upload only `mimes:jpeg,jpg,png`   @Ishan Siddiqui

Comment: try increasing the value of 
 post_max_size  && upload_max_filesize  in php.ini @user11710915